# Ajax jquery php post beginner

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am have a hard time learning how to use ajax and jquery to post a button without reloading the page. Specificly: The form is still reloading the page and no variables are being updated.

Here is the code I am stumbling through.

What I used before I tried Jquery/AJAX. Just php

```
// $_POST['selected_dir'] is set when you click on a folder or link within the explore(r).php    

if (isset($_POST['selected_dir'])) 
   {
      // last selected folder/directory
   $current_dir = $_POST['selected_dir']; 
      // current_dir is the folder we are looking inside of.
      // we make it a $session so that if we click a different submit (RELOAD)
      // within the page it will remember $current_dir;
   $_SESSION['selected_dir'] = $current_dir; //
   }

   else // if $_post isint set but $_session is
   if (isset($_SESSION['selected_dir']))
      {
 $current_dir = $_SESSION['selected_dir'];
 }
 else
 {
 // default folder/directory
 $current_dir = "$root";  //'D:\Hosting\538\html';
 }

<form action='explore.php' method='post'>
     <input type='image'
       src='$folder_icon' 
       alt='Submit'
            name=''
       value='submit'/>

       <input type='hidden' 
              value='$f_path/$value'
         name='selected_dir'/>

       <input type='submit' 
         value='$value'
         name='$value' 
         class='submit_into_link'/>
</form>
```

so that worked great except everytime you click the image or the link the page reloads.
I finally came to the conclusion i need to use jquery and ajax and I never even used javascript up till now. Ive been reading through tutorials and i cant really connect the dots to make this work

I have this in my header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

I have this at the top of my page within the body

```
$.ajax
    ({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'explore_be.php', 
    data: data, success: 
    success function(data, textStatus, jqXHR),
    complete: function(),
    dataType: dataType 
    });
```

I have a few questions about the code above. I'm not sure how to use it.
Do I need to put this ajax code inside an onclick function? seems like some examples ive looked through in jquery use something like this..

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
 $(".flip").click(function() // this is a piece of code i got from w3schools.com
 });
```

.flip above is a class. I have seen them use button when talking about

```
 <button>
```

but what about a button within a form with a specific input id? Or should i just add to the form input
onclick="clicked()" then put the ajax in that function? Does the ajax need be in the     $(document).ready(function()) as well?

What should i put for datatype?

I put my php code in the explore_be.php file.

explore_be.php

```
 // $_POST['selected_dir'] is set when you click on a folder or link within the explore(r).php    

if (isset($_POST['selected_dir'])) 
   {
      // last selected folder/directory
   $current_dir = $_POST['selected_dir']; 
      // current_dir is the folder we are looking inside of.
      // we make it a $session so that if we click a different submit (RELOAD)
      // within the page it will remember $current_dir;
   $_SESSION['selected_dir'] = $current_dir; //
   }

   else // if $_post isint set but $_session is
   if (isset($_SESSION['selected_dir']))
      {
 $current_dir = $_SESSION['selected_dir'];
 }
 else
 {
 // default folder/directory
 $current_dir = "$root";  //'D:\Hosting\538\html';
 }
```

Is that all there is to the code behind page?

I changed my forms to have no action but added an onclick They are still reloading the page. What do I need to do to the form inputs to stop that?

My new form looks like this

```
<form action='' method='post'>
     <input type='image'
       src='$folder_icon' 
       alt='Submit'
            name=''
       onclick='clickity()'
            value='submit'/>

       <input type='hidden' 
              value='$f_path/$value'
         name='selected_dir'/>

       <input type='submit' 
         value='$value'
         name='$value' 
         onclick='clickity()'
                   class='submit_into_link'/>
</form>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

html

```
<form action='explore.php' method='post' id='myForm'>
```

jquery

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event){  //added event
    event.preventDefault(); //added to prevent submit
    $.ajax
        ({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'explore_be.php', 
        data: data, success: 
        success function(data, textStatus, jqXHR),
        complete: function(),
        dataType: dataType 
    });


});
```

edit: remove the onclick events you added in your edit

Comment: I like this example best so far. It makes the most sense to me, however putting anything in the action field except what Jonur suggested 'javascript:;' seems to reload the page. When I used your example including return false; and removing the onlcick it still reloaded the page. btw You think I need to wrap the code behind php into some kinda of java function to get the variables?

Comment: Also does this form submit function need to be inside of the $(document).ready(function())?

Comment: no, it does not need to be inside document ready.  also check updated code

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='javascript:;' method='post'>
     <input type='image'
       src='$folder_icon' 
       alt='Submit'
            name=''
       onclick='clickity();'/>

       <input type='hidden' 
              value='$f_path/$value'
         name='selected_dir'/>

       <input type='submit' 
         value='$value'
         name='$value' 
         onclick='clickity();' 
         class='submit_into_link'/>
</form>
```

Firstly change this and tell me if it's ok and also tell me why you need 2 submits on the same form?

Comment: I changed that and it actually did stop the page from reloading. I am not sure if this is a good answer but certainly part of my problem seems to be solved. I used two inputs, one for a link and one for an image. this was the only way I knew how using only php but from the other answers here it seems I can look for the form being clicked and not the specific input which seems to eleminate the need for 2.  Using your example would the ajax function go inside of the $(document).ready(function())?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying three things at a time. which will make things complex to find where the error lies. Just use ajax without jquery with a small example. Then extend it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getdata(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","response.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<input type='submit' onclick='getdata(input)'>
<div id='result'>
</div>
<body>
```

Comment: I agree generally with the principle that one can try to learn too much in one go. But in the case of AJAX, I'd say: always use a library, right from the very start. There's less jQuery code than raw JS, and browser differences are hidden from view `:)`.